# How to pre-allocate empty class object which is then created within curly braces of if statement?

Tags: c++

How do I avoid the error of the object not being allocated in this scope when using it outside the if statement?

I have tried to declare an empty class but struggled to see how exactly.

```
class mvn {
public:
    int hello;
    mvn(int hello_) {
        hello = hello_;
    }
    ~mvn();
    int MyMethod() {
        return hello;
    }
}


int main() {
    bool firstrun = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {

            if (firstrun == true)
            {
                mvn my_instance(100);
                firstrun = false;
            }


            // do more things with the instance which in reality is a wrapper
            // to random number generation and needs to be created on first run

        }


    return my_instance.MyMethod();
}
```

This would not compile saying that `my_instance` is declared out of scope, because it is local to the curly braces.

Is there a way to pre-allocate an empty instance so that it can be overwritten if `firstrun` is true but not thereafter, just so the compiler knows 'it's there'? My real implementation is much more complex than this of course, but this is a MWE.

EDIT: I added another element that i probably should not have abstracted away from. It's the fact that I simply cannot (or should not) create the instance more than once as each recreation is the re-seeding of a random number generator, which should be seeded/created from within (because this happens on multiple threads).

Now one thing I got was that everyone else here knows a lot more than I do. I am not sure which way is the best way to swing this and/or if the 'singleton pattern' is applicable here?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher how do you mean? SHould I declare anything as static first? Sorry I don't really understand.

Comment: yup fixed that,

Comment: While your compiler may not care about whitespace, it makes a big difference in readability. Please make sure code you share here is formated in a consistent way that makes it easy to read. This is not only a show of respect for your fellow users but will improve the odds that users will take the time to read your question making it more likely that you will get useful feedback and answers.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to simulate local static variable

Comment: `main` can only be run once though.

Comment: @eerorika agreed, I suppose this function is probably not called `main` in OP original code.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher so if I declared the instance static I any number of repetitions that the wrapping function is called, the instance remains as it was when first called? Here the 'instance' is a random number generator that must be seeded once and then left alone.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happens. You get the same variable with the previous state from the previous call.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher ah great, I was just reading up on the static keyword and worry about about 'all instances' (IBM documentation). DO you think if all this happens inside an instance of yet another, encapsulating class, that the static variable would penetrate across threads? In other words, is static declaration thread-safe i.e. stays on its thread? Won't pester you anymore with this.

Comment: static means that it is static accross threads. If you want thread local storage, then you need C++17 and the thread_local keyword on top of static (AFAIK).

Comment: From your example, you might directly have `mvn my_instance(100);` outside of the loop, in `main` scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a static variable: "just so the compiler knows 'it's there'":

```
int myMethod()
{
    static mvn my_instance(100);
    return my_instance.MyMethod();
}
```

The second time, the compiler will reuse the existing variable.

Still, not a great design (see "singleton" pattern online).

Comment: thanks for your answer! But hang on a sec, would that not mean that a method declares its own instance? I will look up singleton pattern for sure.

Comment: That just means that this function will reuse an object for all the calls to it. Here, it's not a method, it's just a simple function.

Comment: @Hirek Beware that singleton is often regarded as an anti-pattern. It's often used in inappropriate ways as a quick fix that leads to trouble down the line. There exists legitimate uses for the pattern but it's a significantly overused pattern. I assume this is why Matthieu says *"Still, not a great design (see "singleton" pattern online)."*. This design is essentially an implementation of the singleton pattern and is likely a design decision that merits being reconsidered.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's a dangerous pattern.

Comment: Static variables, global variables and singletons are all equally bad.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux the issue here is that my hands are tied somewhat. The optimiser library I use forces me to inherit from it and I need to call in another header only library (class) that allows me to draw from a multivariate normal. I understand that the code as is looks very contrived. However, in the end thread_local static worked out really well and I think is merited since the calling of this class's method on each thread is at the heart of what main is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

`std::optional` is a way to allow future initialization

```
std::optional<mvn> my_instance;

if (some_condition) {
   my_instance.emplace(100);
}

// do more things with the instance

if (my_instance) {
    my_instance->MyMethod();
}
```

Comment: thanks so much @Jarod42 just wondering does it work with arguments as well? Will read up on std::optional!

Comment: The issue is persistence of the object across calls, not optionality.

Comment: @Hirek: I use `100` as argument as you.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: persistence needed for OP was unclear, but with his last Edit (usage in a loop), optional might be used (even if it is unclear why OP uses local scope for initialization :/)

Comment: @Jarod42 it's local because it should be private to the thread, so there is another class wrapping all of this that I use to shield data from commuting across multiple parallel threads. The only alternative I could see is handing my method an instance of this class but I don't yet know how to pass instances by reference.

Comment: @Hirek: `std::ref` might help, or pass lambda with capture by reference.

Answer (score 3):

It may sound a bit old school, but it looks like a classic case of dynamic allocation to me, so a pointer would do the trick. Use `std::unique_ptr<mvn>` or some of its brethren.

**edit:**

Ok, to clarify this a bit:

```
#include<memory>

class mvn {
public:
    int hello;
    mvn(int hello_) {
        hello = hello_;
    }
    ~mvn() {};
    int MyMethod() {
        return hello;
    }
};


int main() {
    bool firstrun = true;
    std::unique_ptr<mvn> mvn_ptr(nullptr);

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {

            if (firstrun == true)
            {
                mvn_ptr.reset(new mvn(100));
                firstrun = false;
            }

        }

    return mvn_ptr->MyMethod();
}
```

This compiles and runs.

```
~/tmp $ g++ fun.cpp -std=c++11
~/tmp $ ./a.out 
~/tmp $ echo "$?"
100
```

Comment: THanks! @AndreasT but what if the constructor takes an argument as well? I have edited the question a bit to make the origin clear.

Comment: Erm, it doesn't matter? See the example provided.

Comment: thanks again for pointing me to this great utility and I believe this is the right way to solve the problem, as in using tools in their intended way. Unfortunately, i obtain segmentation faults with OpenMP when I parallelize. Should there be additional directives? (Error code is SIGSEGV 11)

Comment: @Hirek How can you parallelise it if the object you're using is created in one particular iteration? Assuming you use the object in other iterations (this is not shown in your question)

Comment: In your question you mentioned nothing of OpenMP or potential race conditions, which is probably what you are running into. I guess you are using one of the #pragma_for constructs of OpenMP. Please put this in a new question. Stringing people along like you have done here is really not in the spirit of this site. Your question has been about variable scoping.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler approach is to simply make your calculation logic a member function of another class. Then you can make your object a member of that class, and it will be created there as a necessity for the first run.

```
struct mvn {
    int hello;
    mvn(int hello) : hello(hello) { }
    int MyMethod() { return hello; }
}

struct wrapper {
    mvn m;
    wrapper(int hello) : m(hello) { }
    int go() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ...
        return m.MyMethod();
    }
}

int main() {
    wrapper w(42);
    return w.go();
}
```

That way you don't need to allocate anything dynamically, and you avoid the need for an `if` altogether.

If you have multiple `go()` functions or simply want to parametrize, write it as such instead:

```
template<typename F>
int wrapper::go(F&& f) {
    std::forward<F>(f)(m);
    return m.MyMethod();
}
```

Where `F` is any callable taking `mvn&`, e.g. `[](mnv& m) { for (...) m.foo(); }`.

And of course every call to `go()` will use the pre-existing `m` inside the `wrapper` object; you just need to share this object around. Calling it from different threads is another matter, and might require sufficient precautions to avoid breaking the state of `m`.

Answer (score -1):

Move the `if` into a function that `return`s a `mvn` instance.

```
mvn make_mvn(bool firstrun) {
    if(firstrun == true)
    {
        mvn my_instance(100);
        firstrun = false;
    }
    return mvn(0); // substitute as necessary
}

int main() {
    bool firstrun = true;
    mvn my_instance = make_mvn(firstrun);
    // do more things with the instance
    return my_instance.MyMethod();
}
```

You can change `make_mvn` as necessary.

Comment: What is the point of setting the local `firstrun` to false when it isn't read in the function after that?

Comment: What would be the point of returning a new instance each time? You are not reusing the object (see OP question).

Comment: Since the issue is ensuring `my_instance` exists for later use, this provides a method of guaranteeing that.  If it needs to be reused, the author can preserve the returned instance using whichever means they feel best (including storing it in a `static`).

Comment: This method doesn't ensure that `my_instance` exists for later use. It has automatic storage and stops existing at the end of the scope.

Comment: Exactly, doesn't guarantee anything.

Comment: You have to `firstrun` variables there, and I'm pretty sure that wasn't the intent. And then you create the `my_instance` and don't use it, returning `mvn(0)` every time. And even in the fixed form, it's still a bad idea.